# Detect non-uniform direction in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

**Background**

Given a matrix like this:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5;
     2 3 4 5 6;
     3 4 5 6 7;
     4 5 6 7 8]
```

We can see that each number is increasing both to the right and down. However the direction doesn't matter, as long as the direction/slope is uniform.

This can be tested by:

```
> gradient(X) >= 0;

ans = [1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1]
```

and

```
> gradient(X') >= 0 % transpose of X

ans = [1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1 1]
```

In this example I am assuming that the data is increasing right/down, it would not be a complicated task to extend to any uniform direction.

This can be combined into the full test:

```
> all(all(gradient(X) > 0)) && all(all(gradient(X') > 0))
    ans = 1
```

**Question:**

How can I detect any deviation from this uniform direction and "fix" it.
The fix should involve interpolating a value from the surrounding points.

**Note:**

In practice these matrices are quite large and contain values which might only differ by tiny amounts.
I am assuming at the moment that there will only be one deviation at a time, they won't be grouped together: `[1 2 3 2 4 5] (2 is an error)` for example, rather than `[1 2 3 2 1 4] ([2 1] is an error)`

**Edit:**

`[1 2 3 2 4 5]` should become `[1 2 3 3.5 4 5]` Where 3.5 is the interpolated value of the surrounding points (in this case the average of 3 and 4).

**Edit2:**

Ignore the interpolation part, I will work that out later.

Given

```
 X =

 1     2     3     4     5
 2     3     2     5     6
 3     4     5     6     7
 4     5     6     7     8
```

2 is obviously the "error". I would like the following as output:

```
2 3 4
3 2 5
4 5 6
```

Which is the error value and the surrounding points. From these points I will do a 2D interpolation to replace 2 with (hopefully) 4, using 3, 3, 5, and 5 (ignoring the corners 2, 4, 4, and 6).

Comment: What is the correct output for `[1 2 3 2 4 5]`?

Comment: The 2 should be removed and replaced with the average of 3 and 4 to get 3.5: `[1 2 3 3.5 4 5]`

Comment: Only one deviation by rows or also by columns? Because it can happen that while you fix a value in one direction (e.g. the row) you spoil the other direction (i.e. the column).

Comment: Columns as well, I just used a row example because it is easier to show.

Comment: The if you have X = [1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 2 5 6; 3 4 5 6 7; 4 5 6 7 8]; then the entry at the second row and third column should be interpolated by the average of all FOUR neighbours, i.e. (3 + 3 + 5 + 5) / 4. Correct?

Comment: There is some issue with the average. Assume you have the neighbours 1 to the left, 10 above, 11 to the right and below. The average is 8.25 which is below 10. Similar example could be created for the average of two, where one direction breaks the rules for the other direction.

Comment: Suppose you have 1 on the left, 10 above, 7 to the right, 11 below? You need to change 7 as well, right? And set it at least at 11?

Comment: I just used average because it was 1D, but really I would need to do 2D interpolation. Ignore the interpolation part for now, if you can output the error val and its surrounding points I will be very happy. I will update the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update it seems like you will be able to 'correct the errors' by yourself. That only leaves the question of how to find them. However, I have also included a suggestion on how to interpolate a value and use this.

**Finding the errors**

Assuming this is your matrix:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5;
     2 3 2 5 6;
     3 4 5 6 7;
     4 5 6 7 8]
```

Assuming you have a vertically and horizontally increasing matrix, here is how to find anomalies:

```
idx = [zeros(1,size(x,2)); diff(x)<0] | [zeros(size(x,1),1), diff(x,[],2)<0]
```

If you want to have the row and column indices, you can do this:

```
[myRows, myCols] = find(idx)
```

If you are looking at a decresing pattern vertically, you can use `diff(x)<0` for example. If you are looking for an exact difference (always one?) you can check whether the difference is equal to your value, but you will need to be aware of the dangers incurred by floating point calculations and rounding issues.

**Filling the errors**

My suggestion for you would be to first determine for each value, what the `backup` value is in case you want to replace it. This can be done by applying a filter for example:

```
altValues = filter2([0 1 0;1 0 1; 0 1 0]/4,x);
```

Now replacing the found errors can be done like this:

```
x(idx) = altValues(idx);
```

This will give the following result:

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 2     3     4     5     6
 3     4     5     6     7
 4     5     6     7     8
```

If you want to consider the diagonal differences, you may want to use this filter instead:

```
altValues = filter2(ones(3)/9,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this to find indicies of error values for 1D array:

```
A=[1 2 3 2 4 5];
Index1=find(diff(A)-abs(diff(A)));
Index1=Index1=+1
```

For 2D case:

```
A=[1 2 3 2; 1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 1 1 1 1];
[Index1,Index2]=find(diff(A,1,1)-abs(diff(A,1,1)));%wrong gradient along x
Index1=Index1+1;
[Index1a,Index2a]=find(diff(A,1,2)-abs(diff(A,1,2)));%wrong gradient along y
Index2a=Index2a+1;
```

Comment: Isn't `find(diff(v)-abs(diff(v)))` the same as `find(diff(v)<0)` ?